# Trying to create text file using user-input with Batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line

```
echo.
set /p textfileName=What would you like the file to be named? 
echo.
echo On the line below, write what text you would like the file to contain:
echo.
set /p textfileContents= 
echo %textfileWrite% >> %textfileWriteName%.txt
echo.
echo Your file has been created and is in the same directory as this batch file.
echo It is named %textfilename%.txt
echo.
goto inputCommand
```

Whenever I try to use this code, it comes up with "Echo is off" (from @echo off previously in the file) but not what the user inputted. Then, if I run it again in the same instance, it will create the previous file but not the one I just told it to create.

I've tried having > and it didn't work, >> didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few problems going on here.  First, you mentioned `@echo`, but looking at your code, you're just using `echo`.

Also, I think there's some confusion with your variables.  You capture the user's filename into `textfilename`, but then write to `textfileWriteName`.  You capture the user's file contents in `textfileContents`, but then write `textfileWrite` to the file.

Finally, you specify a `goto` label that doesn't exist.  Maybe this is part of a larger batch file that you just partially copied?

Anyhoo, I think this is along the lines of what you intended:

```
@echo off
set /p textfileName=What would you like the file to be named? 
@echo On the line below, write what text you would like the file to contain:
set /p textfileContents= 
@echo %textfileContents% > %textfileName%.txt
@echo Your file has been created and is in the same directory as this batch file.
@echo It is named %textfilename%.txt
```

Comment: Yes, this is part of a larger file :)

Comment: nope, it doesn't seem to work. just creates a file with no name and inside says "ECHO is off."

EDIT: weird thing is that it works isolated, just not with the rest of my code

Comment: @xDarockerx Are you referring to this solution?  It works on my system.

Comment: Like I stated before, it works isolated and as its own batch file but when I add it to the rest of my code it won't work. The first time it will create a file with no title that just has the text "ECHO is off" in it, and if I just press space down it will do it again, but with the variables I had typed in for the Text File Name and Contents.

Comment: Is this code inside a block (between `(` and `)`? if yes, you need "delayed expansion" (search for it at this site, you will find all you need)

Comment: @xDarockerx So... it's a little difficult to propose a solution if you don't show all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

you have serious space issues in your variables " text filename and text contents"
avoid spaces in your variables or if you must use more than one word in your variable use symbols to separate the strings .. the code below should work fine

```
@echo off
: main_menu
echo.
echo.
set /p notf=name of text file :
set / p cof=contents of file :
echo %cof%>>"%notf%.txt"
echo %notf% text file was  successfuly created...
echo.
echo.
echo press any key to return to main menu
pause>null
cls
goto main_menu
```